# Caption, prev next, play and pause not displaying

Tags: views

I am using a Views Slideshow module to create a slideshow on the homepage. For the Image filed, I've enabled the the caption, Create prev/next controls, Create play/pause button etc... However, none of these seem to be displaying. What am I missing?

Comment: Check you markup if it is there.

Comment: There is some settings in the views page. did you checked that ?

Comment: When you click on the setting link,which is displayed in the dialog box where we choose SLIDESHOW as the format for displaying images.There is a checkbox which you have to enable in ordet ro show the controls and then assign the weight to them so that controls can be displayed at proper place.

Comment: Thank you @neetumorwani
I've selected the checkbox but the links are not displaying. What weight should I assign to it? I didn't set this... perhaps this is why it's not displayed anywhere...

Comment: There is a checkbox present with CONTROLS as its label.When you check that checkbox, dropdown menu for assigning weight to the CONTROLS appears.Assign the weight to the controls accordingly where you want your controls to be displayed.